# How to resolve fixed div positions in HTML

Tags: html

i would like to know why my divs are not fixed. I pass a position x and y on the html but depending of the screen resolution or if a maximize the html or reduce his width or heigth.
I want that this divs are always in the exactly position.

Thanks

http://pastie.org/3281032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you set the position to absolute, you are putting that div in the absolute spot according to the axis you specified, no matter how you resize, it'll be there.

I suppose you want the text to be in the exact spot according to the table, am I correct? If so, you might want to put the position to "relative". I've modified your code a big to illustrate:

```
<table width="670" border="1" style="height:300px" align="center">

    <tr>
        <td>

            <div class="Estilo1" style="position: relative; margin-top:50px; margin-left: 50px;">Texto sobrhhe </div>

            <div class="Estilo1" style="position: absolute; top: 222px; left: 490px;">
                Texto sobrhhe
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Hope this is what you are looking for =)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you should use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`.